# Swift pass struct in completion block

Tags: swift, networking, struct

I am new to swift, I have

`struct User{...}`

trying to return this User from network call completion block

```
func prof(completion: ((_ user: User?) -> ())? = nil) {
  ...
  let user = ...//created successfully
  completion?(user)
}
```

in my view controller

```
    api.prof { user in
    // user nil
    }
```

Please clarify how to return user correctly?

Comment: kindly add complete code of prof.

Comment: You should call `completion?(user)` inside the API `completion` block that you didn't post.

Comment: what happens in `let user = ...`

Comment: Thanks, actually it is working without any changes. Anyway thanks for help with code improvements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a friendly advice to stop this mess with closures. Use type aliases to avoid complexity in function declarations.

```swift
typealias UserCompletion = (User?) -> Void
```

Now in your function:

```swift
func prof(completion: UserCompletion?) {
  ...
  completion?(user)
}
```

View Controller:

```swift
api.prof { user in 
   if let user = user {
      //do something with user
   }

}
```

Second, why do you want your completion to be with an optional user? Ideally you'd want to go for an error if user creation fails. You could use `Result<User, Error>` for that one.